# Any way to load a new java process without a file?

Tags: java, file, process, jar, classloader

So, I have a file that runs, say begin.jar, I want it to create a new java process with update.jar, without caching it. I know I can use classloaders, but that doesn't create a new process. The reason I want a new process, is I want the update.jar to delete the begin.jar, and write a new one. It works like this: begin.jar loads, creates a new process with update.jar, begin.jar closes, update.jar deletes and replaces begin.jar, runs it, and closes. How can I open a new java process without a cached file?

Comment: To my ear, this has a ring of the XY Problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What it is that you're actually trying to achieve? Some sort of software auto-update?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve an auto-updater, but I don't want to use file caching.

Comment: It might help to say why not. Otherwise it sounds like a rather artificial constraint that makes a fairly easy problem harder.

Comment: It's artificial, I wanted to see if I could create an auto-updater that kept the jar independent, not relying on other files.

Comment: What cache? Are you using JWS?

Comment: A file cache, like writing an updater to the hard drive.

Comment: So who is forcing you to use file caching? What's the question here?

Comment: The point of the question is, how can I split a thread off in another process, without a new file?